# Problems with layout function and node size in R with igraph package

Tags: r, networking, plot, graph, igraph

I'm using the following code to create a network from a dataframe:

```
edges <- data.frame(working.cd.data$org_name, 
         working.cd.data$org_name2)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, directed=F)
net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T)
plot(net, edge.color="blue", vertex.color="gray50", vertex.label=NA, 
     vertex.size = 5, layout=layout_with_lgl)
plot(net, edge.color="blue", vertex.color="gray50", vertex.label=NA, 
    vertex.size = 5, layout=layout_with_lgl, vertex.size=betweenness(net))
```

Both plot functions provide this graph ->  [NETWORK GRAPH PLOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37IUD.png)

The problem is that my graph is not applying the layout argument or the vertex size argument.  Also, I'm not receiving any error messages or other messages.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks, Elliot.

Comment: the second plot call has two vertex.size arguments

Comment: Oh, wow.  Thanks that actually fixed the node size issue.  I'm still having issues with the layout argument.

Comment: I cant tell from looking at one plot if the layout algorithm  is working(perhaps someone who knows this stuff might??) , and again note that you added it to both plot calls. Are you able to show some code that reproduces your issues, say using an example from igraph?

Comment: I created a test network and used different layouts with the desired effect. I would suggest trying different layout functions until you get one that is aesthetically pleasing. Getting a good looking network layout is more of an art than a science.

Comment: @emilliman5, Thanks for your reply.  I think my issue is that I actually have a great many vertices that have connections to one other vertex.  I am now trying to separate the main graph from the smaller, disconnected graphs.